# Tkinter Duration Timer—What method will allow this duration "timer" to update?

Tags: python, tkinter

The current "time_elapsed" duration appears as text in the tkinter window, but doesn't update like a timer. I can only assume I'm missing an important method that would allow the duration to update. I'm sure the answer is simple and I'm just looking too deeply into it. Any suggestions?

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime, time

root = Tk() 
root.title("Debut Date") 
root.geometry("600x400")
root.config(bg="#000000")

#date/time of first post (August 21, 6:30:54pm):
Year   = 2020
Month  = 8
Day    = 21
Hour   = 18
Minute = 30
Second = 54

DOP = datetime.datetime(Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute,Second) #DOP represents "Date of Post" and 
is defined by "Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", & "Second"
DSP = (datetime.datetime.now() - DOP) #DSP represents "Duration Since Post" and is defined by 
datetime.now() minus "Date of Post"

duration = DSP.total_seconds() #total number of seconds between DOP and DSP

years   = divmod(duration, 31536000)
days    = divmod(years[1], 86400)             #uses remainder of years to calculate days
hours   = divmod(days[1], 3600)               #uses remainder of days to calculate hours
minutes = divmod(hours[1], 60)                #uses remainder of hours to calculate minutes
seconds = divmod(minutes[1], 1)               #uses remainder of minutes to calculate seconds

def update_time():
   time_elapsed = ("%d:%d:%d:%d:%d" % (years[0], days[0], hours[0], minutes[0], seconds[0]))
   label.config(text = time_elapsed)
   label.after(1000, update_time)

   label = Label(root, text="", font=("Helvetica", 50), fg="#ffffff", bg="#000000", bd=50)
   label.pack()

   update_time()
   root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Move the `label = Label(...)` and everything after it outside of the function. Also you need to constantly update your: `years`, `days`, ... variables because right now they don't change each time you update the label's text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
from tkinter import *
import datetime, time

root = Tk() 
root.title("Debut Date") 
root.geometry("600x400")
root.config(bg="#000000")

#date/time of first post (August 21, 6:30:54pm):
Year   = 2020
Month  = 8
Day    = 21
Hour   = 18
Minute = 30
Second = 54

DOP = datetime.datetime(Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute,Second) #DOP represents "Date of Post" and  is defined by "Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", & "Second"


def update_time():
    DSP = (datetime.datetime.now() - DOP) #DSP represents "Duration Since Post" and is defined by datetime.now() minus "Date of Post"

    duration = DSP.total_seconds() #total number of seconds between DOP and DSP

    years   = divmod(duration, 31536000)
    days    = divmod(years[1], 86400)             #uses remainder of years to calculate days
    hours   = divmod(days[1], 3600)               #uses remainder of days to calculate hours
    minutes = divmod(hours[1], 60)                #uses remainder of hours to calculate minutes
    seconds = divmod(minutes[1], 1)               #uses remainder of minutes to calculate seconds

    time_elapsed = ("%d:%d:%d:%d:%d" % (years[0], days[0], hours[0], minutes[0], seconds[0]))
    label.config(text = time_elapsed)
    label.after(1000, update_time)

label = Label(root, text="", font=("Helvetica", 50), fg="#ffffff", bg="#000000", bd=50)
label.pack()

update_time()
root.mainloop()
```

Like I pointed out in the comment:

- You need to move everything after (including the) `label = Label(...)` outside of the function.
- You also need to update your variables each time the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

Your `update_time` has three critical flaws. For one, it calls itself both with `after` and also directly. The call to `update_time()` causes an infinite loop.

The second problem is that you're calling `root.mainloop()` inside of `update_time`. The vast majority of time, you should only ever call `mainloop()` a single time during the life of your program.

The third problem is that each time `update_time` is called it creates a new label. You should be creating the label only once, so you need to move the creation of the label to outside of the function. You can update the label by calling  the `configure` method to change the `text` option.

Comment: 4th problem is that the variables that are used to get the new label's text are static so they aren't going to change.